# git pide contraseña de antiguo user

Tags: git, contraseña

tengo problemas con git. al tratar de usar git me pide contraseña de usuario anterior de bitbucket, el pc que estoy usando es de mi trabajo. Esto me sucede de forma constante, por ejemplo:
[image: ejemplo]

Estoy atenta a sus comentarios

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar `git config --global --unset-all user.name` para eliminar todos los usuarios de ese repositorio local

Comment: gracias lo probare !!!

Comment: Ok!, me cuentas @Regy